# Using iText for PDF export

Tags: java, html, pdf-generation, itext

In our Spring application, we have export in multiple pages in different sections , the export will include both the data and the graphs.

Could you please direct me which is the best option for the export to PDF, we are planning to use iText, so for different pages, can we create templates, whether it will take css styles.

whether the HTML template or ftl template work, or do we have any other options which is good in performance and considering that there are many sections where we need export

Regards
Hari

Comment: As you do not explain what you want to export (in which format the data to export is) and how the result should be, it's hard to answer. IText is a general purpose pdf library, so quite likely you *can* use it in your project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `iTextSharp` recognizes simple `HTML` and `CSS`, hence you may export the page with them. Please check [this](http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/03/23/generating-pdfs-within-java-using-itext/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we are using Java, can we use the iTextSharp in java also

Comment: @user2907217, please check my edited answer and request you to upvote if my answer helps you.

Comment: @user2907217 *we are using Java, can we use the iTextSharp in java also* - iTextSharp is the .Net port of the original Java library iText. Thus, no problem here.